# Read in float from UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have been working on a little currency converter for iOS and wanted to read a float from a `UITextField`. Unfortunately I'm not able to read a float from the `UITextField`. I did some research on the Internet but none of the methods I tried worked. I am new to Objective-C and this is my first own post so feel free to give me feedback and advice for future posts too.

Here's the code in ViewController.m:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Currencyz
//
//  Created by Daniel Putzer on 21/08/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Daniel Putzer. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize Dollar, Euro, DollarValue, EuroValue, Result, ReadIn;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setDollar: 0];
    [self setResult: @""];
}

- (IBAction) ReadEuro:(id)sender
{
    Euro = [EuroValue.text floatValue];
}

- (void) Calculate
{
    Dollar = 1.13245 * Euro;
    Result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", Dollar];
}

- (IBAction)CalculateDollar:(id)sender
{
    [self Calculate];
    [DollarValue setText: Result];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And here's ViewController.h:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Currencyz
//
//  Created by Daniel Putzer on 21/08/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Daniel Putzer. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    float Euro;
    float Dollar;
    NSString *Result;
    NSString *ReadIn;

    IBOutlet UILabel *DollarValue;
    IBOutlet UITextField *EuroValue;
}

@property float Euro;
@property float Dollar;
@property NSString *Result;
@property NSString *ReadIn;

@property IBOutlet UILabel *DollarValue;
@property IBOutlet UITextField *EuroValue;

@end
```

I don't understand why it doesn't set the variable `Euro` to the amount entered in the `UITextField`.

Comment: you are using `IBAction` and you don't call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setDollar: 0];
    [self setResult: @""];
    [self ReadEuro];
}

- (void) ReadEuro
{
    Euro = [EuroValue.text floatValue];
    NSLog("Euro value is : %0.02f", Euro);
}
```

try this and see if this prints your value.

Comment: If I do that it asks me for an id

[self ReadEuro: (id) ];

Comment: Ok i figured the id problem out
The label still doesn't show a number tho